# How can I overcome inconsistent behaviour of snprintf in different UNIX-like operating systems?

Tags: c, cross-platform, buffer-overflow, buffer-overrun

Per man pages, snprintf is returning number of bytes written from glibc version 2.2 onwards. But on lower versions of libc2.2 and HP-UX, it returns a positive integer, which could lead to a buffer overflow.

How can one overcome this and write portable code?

Edit : For want of more clarity

This code is working perfectly in lib 2.3

```
    if ( snprintf( cmd, cmdLen + 1, ". %s%s", myVar1, myVar2 )  != cmdLen )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "\nError: Unable to  copy bmake command!!!");
        returnCode = ERR_COPY_FILENAME_FAILED;
    }
```

It returns the length of the string (10) on Linux. But the same code is returning a positive number that is greater than the number of characters printed on HP-UX machine. Hope this explanation is fine.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit?  It is not clear how the return value type would lead to a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could create a snprintf wrapper that returns -1 for each case when there is not enough space in the buffer.

See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) for more docs. It has also an example which threats all the cases.

```
  while (1) {
      /* Try to print in the allocated space. */
      va_start(ap, fmt);
      n = vsnprintf (p, size, fmt, ap);
      va_end(ap);
      /* If that worked, return the string. */
      if (n > -1 && n < size)
         return p;
      /* Else try again with more space. */
      if (n > -1)    /* glibc 2.1 */
         size = n+1; /* precisely what is needed */
      else           /* glibc 2.0 */
         size *= 2;  /* twice the old size */
      if ((np = realloc (p, size)) == NULL) {
         free(p);
         return NULL;
      } else {
         p = np;
      }
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't work well, because a current valid snprintf() can return -1 on error.

Comment: The -1 case is treated when it allocates twice the old size (/* glibc 2.0 */ comment ).

The printf function has 2 behaviours:

1. It returns -1 to tell you that the buffer is not big enough
2. It returns the number of bytes needed (you need to compare to see if it is ok)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered a portable implementation of printf? I looked for one a little while ago and settled on trio.

http://daniel.haxx.se/projects/trio/

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still unclear.  The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) linked to speaks thus:

> The functions snprintf() and vsnprintf() **do not write more than size bytes** (including
>   the trailing '\0'). If the output was truncated due to this limit then the return value is the number of characters (not including the trailing '\0') which **would** have been written to the final string if enough space had been available. Thus, **a return value of size or more means that the output was truncated.**

So, if you want to know if your output was truncated:

```
int ret = snprintf(cmd, cmdLen + 1, ". %s%s", myVar1, myVar2 ) == -1)
if(ret == -1 || ret > cmdLen)
{
    //output was truncated
}
else
{
    //everything is groovy
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a whole host of problems with *printf portability, and realistically you probably want to follow one of three paths:

1. Require a c99 compliant *printf, because 9 years should be enough for anyone, and just say the platform is broken otherwise.
2. Have a my_snprintf() with a bunch of #ifdef's for the specific platforms you want to support all calling the vsnprintf() underneath (understanding the lowest common denominator is what you have).
3. Just carry around a copy of vsnprintf() with your code, for simple usecases it's actually [pretty simple](http://www.and.org/texts/simple_printf.c) and for others you'd probably want to look at [vstr](http://www.and.org/vstr/) and you'll get customer formatters for free.

...as other people have suggested you can do a hack merging #1 and #2, just for the -1 case, but that is risky due to the fact that c99 *printf can/does return -1 in certain conditions.

Personally I'd recommend just going with [a string library like ustr](http://www.and.org/ustr/), which does the simple workarounds for you and gives you managed strings for free. If you really care you can combine with [vstr](http://www.and.org/vstr/).

Answer (score 0):

I have found one portable way to predict and/or limit the number of characters returned by sprintf and related functions, but it's inefficient and many consider it inelegant.

What you do is create a temporary file with tmpfile(), fprintf() to that (which reliably returns the number of bytes written), then rewind and read all or part of the text into a buffer.

Example:

```
int my_snprintf(char *buf, size_t n, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    int nchars;
    FILE *tf = tmpfile();

    va_start(va, n);
    nchars = vfprintf(tf, fmt, va);
    if (nchars >= (int) n)
        nchars = (int) n - 1;
    va_end(va);
    memset(buf, 0, 1 + (size_t) nchars);

    if (nchars > 0)
    {
        rewind(tf);
        fread(buf, 1, (size_t) nchars, tf);
    }

    fclose(tf);

    return nchars;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the much superior asprintf() instead.

It's a GNU extension, but it's worth copying to the target platform in the event that it's not natively available.

Comment: asprintf() isn't really better as it isn't std. at all and does behave differently. Also what you get isn't a usefully managed string, like with ustr_dup_fmt() etc.